# Beside creating snippets, are there other ways to quickly create Markdown tables in sublime text 3?

Tags: markdown, sublimetext3, code-snippets, github-flavored-markdown, multimarkdown

I'm talking about writing `table[r]x[c]` and pressing `<tab>` to generate a Markdown table with the required numbers of rows and columns (in GFM or whatever markdown flavor one prefers). I don't feel like making, say 100, snippets for tables of a size up to `10x10`. Is there a way that can automate this table creation process while avoiding keystrokes at the same time?

Thank you for your input.

Comment: Do you find it clumpsy to just use multiline cursor and insert key for writing inside fileds?

Comment: Good point! I didn't think about that! However, I'm still curious if what I suggested could be done. Now I may sound like a total sublime-text beginner here. I am. So bare with me. Thanks for the comment, btw!

Comment: Its ok, but then you could edit to your question by telling you would like an automated solution to avoid keystrokes.

Comment: Since you basically look for something like Emmet for Markdown, I'll start by finding out whether you can extend Emmet on Markdown files and create your own snippets.

Comment: @idleberg I'll check out Emmet and see what I could do. Please put your comment as an answer as it addresses my yes/no question accordingly and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you basically look for something like Emmet for Markdown, I'll start by finding out whether you can extend Emmet on Markdown files and create your own snippets.